# Statically place element at bottom of span element using Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a project that involves a [3 x n] unordered list and am trying to place a link at the bottom of each list entry. The problem is that the height of each list entry is dynamic to the content, as shown in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/finnm/pen/klBsd). How could I style this so that all of the links will appear aligned??

**Source:**

```html
<body class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="row-fluid">
    <li class="span4">
      <h1> Column 1 </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ... laborum.</p>
      <a href="">Some Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
      <h1> Column 2 </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ... consequat.</p>
      <a href="">Some Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
      <h1> Column 3 </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ... pariatur. </p>
      <a href="">Some Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- More similar ul's -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kDCwz

```
ul {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
a {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: This works until you try to stack the li elements differently at other breakpoints.

Comment: Yes, but I believe his requirement to align the links will vanish when he stack the li elements differently.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, but since the person did not specify, it's important to state the limitations of the solution.

Comment: @PrabuRaja the columns are going to have to stack and still contain their individual links. For some reason I cant seem to get this functionality to properly work in my project. Otherwise this would be great for the non-stacked view!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this through some javascript to set the height of the elements.

Here is an example. This piece of code only works as long as there is a single 'p' element in each li. Additionally, I gave your 'ul' an id:'columns'.

```
var maxHeight = 0;

//Get all the 'p' elements in each column
var elem = document.getElementById('columns');
var pElems = elem.getElementsByTagName('p');

// Find out which p element is the tallest
for (var i = 0; i < pElems.length; i++) {
  if( pElems[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight ) {
    maxHeight = pElems[i].offsetHeight;
  }
}

// Set all the elements to the height of the tallest element
for (var i = 0; i < pElems.length; i++) {
  pElems[i].style.height = maxHeight+"px";
}
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gCGpv

Comment: When collapsing, the text from the paragraph hides behind the links.

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little more?